# Download File Google API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I use Node.js and I have a error with the service.api.export .
My console.log send me : Downloading "Manuel Utilisation.pdf..."
Downloaded "Manuel Utilisation.pdf"! but I don't have my downoad from my browser and I have this error :
{ Error: Export only supports Google Docs.}

Before to call this function I do a setcredentiel with my token I have in my bdd.

I use this function to download a file with the idFile :

```
function downloadFiles(auth, fileId) {
 drive.files.get({fileId: fileId }, function (err, metadata) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error GET files :" +  err);
      return process.exit();
    }

    console.log('Downloading %s...', metadata.name);

    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(metadata.name);

    drive.files.export({fileId: fileId, mimeType: 'application/pdf'}).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error downloading file', err);
      process.exit();
    }).pipe(dest);

    dest.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Downloaded %s!', metadata.name);
        return true
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error writing file', err);
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Do you have an idea ? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you want to download a file from Google Driver or download a file and convert it to PDF?

Comment: I want download a file fro google drive to my computer

Comment: your code is correct for a Google Document file - eg. Docs, Sheet, Slides, etc. The answer from tokeryberg is correct if the file is an external format, eg excel, pdf, image, etc. The error message implies that you are trying to export a non-Google Document file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the call to `drive.files.export` throws an error. Luckily you only have to call `drive.files.get`, not `drive.files.export`. According to the example in [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples) your function should look like below. Notice that the example does not give you the metadata of the file you try to download. It might be passed along to the 'on error' function.

```
function downloadFiles(auth, fileId) {
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/some/file/path');
  drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media' })
    .on('end', function() {
     console.log('Downloaded %s!', 'some file');
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.error("Error GET files :" +  err);
      return process.exit();
    })
    .pipe(dest);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time figuring this out, and finally got a download function to work (currently prints in console):

```
function download(auth){
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth})
  var request =  drive.files.export({
    fileId: '_____fileid______',
    mimeType: 'text/html'
  }, {alt: 'media'}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(result)
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs this code works download a file from google drive to given destination.
downloadedfileName is the name of the file given after download.
presentationId is the id of google drive file

````
const downloadFile = async(auth,downloadedfileName,presentationId)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(downloadedfileName);
      const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
      drive.files.get({fileId: presentationId, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'},
        function(err, res){
          res.data
          .on('end', () => {
            resolve(downloadedfileName)
          })
          .on('error', err => {
              reject('Error');
          })
          .pipe(dest);
        }
      );
    });
  }```
````